# Is there any moon without its planet?

Tags: astronomy, definition, planets, moon

Is there any planet without its star?

Is there any moon or any planet wandering in outer space without a definite orbit?

(The name moon or planet used here serves only for size and spherical shape notion.)

Comment: Are you asking about [Rogue planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet)?

Comment: A moon is a term used to describe a natural body that orbits a planet, so moons that wander through space would simply become rogue planets, rogue minor planets or asteroids.

Comment: In fact, our Moon is not really a moon, but a planet on its own just caught in the rotation around and together with the Earth.  Our Moon is the only satellite in the Solar system that would not follow its planet, if the planet is towed away. If the Earth were towed away, the Moon would stay rotating around the Sun, but not follow the Earth. All other satellites in our Solar system would follow their host planet instead.

Comment: A related concept is a [rogue star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_star), which is a star that's (presumably) escaped a galaxy-like structure.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri - Yes, I didn't know this name. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenG - Pluto has a moon so then you claim Pluto is a planet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> João Bosco asked: *Is there any planet without its star?*

They are called [rogue planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet), and of course there can also be rogue moons: for example, a regular planet can lose its moon when a rogue planet comes too close and disrupts the system the moon can be ejected.